# Polymorphing a function that differenciates float numbers from integers (javascript)

Tags: javascript, integer, polymorphism

I need to build a polymorphic function in javascript which can process different types of variables. Integers and float numbers.

Is that possible? Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no integer data type in Javascript, so you would have to check what the values is, i.e. if it has any fractional part:

```
if (value % 1 != 0) {
  // use it as integer
} else {
  // use it as floating point
}
```

Comment: This will fail for numbers without any value after the decimal but still needs to be considered as a fractional number, for ex: 5.0

Comment: @techfoobar `5.0===5` and `5.0` evaluates to `5`. There is no way to distinguish them unless they're `string`s

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes. But depends on how the OP wants it. Even though JS stores 5.0 as just 5 (type number), what if the OP wants 5.0 to be considered as a float in the *polymorphic* function he is talking about..

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, the only possible way here is using strings.

Comment: @techfoobar then he needs to pass a string or use a different function name.

Comment: Yes, pass just the string and determine inside the function if it has a `.` or not etc.

Comment: @JanDvorak Excuse my stupidity but what do you mean by passing a string? I know what it means but not in order to be able to use two functions with the same name..

Comment: @user1770660: It means that if you need to distinguish between `5` and `5.0`, then you have to send it as a string into the function, e.g. `process('5.0')`.

Answer (score 1):

The single best solution is to not rely on method overloading (which is what you are looking for here, really, and which is not available in JS) but instead use different function names and have two functions.

This would mean that you would have to decide at the callside which function to call, but this is similar to other languages (like Java, C#, C), where this decision is made at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Javascript has no function parameters typization. 
Integer and float point numbers are one class type objects - Number